# Increase of a street

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Given is the following task:

A street is to be built along a a route $(x, y)^T = (1, 2)^T \, t - (5, 10)^T$, $t \in [0, 6]$ through a terrain with height $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + \dfrac{1}{6}xy^2 + 2xy + 10x + \dfrac{100}{3}$.
a) Calculate the (normed) increase of the street at the terrain point $(x, y) = (-3, -6)$.
b) Calculate the highest and the lowest point of the street.

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve this task.

In a): Do I only need to calculate the gradient of $f(x,y)$ and then put $(x,y)^T$ in the gradient? The "normed" confuses me. When I read this word my first thoughts are directional derivatives, where it is recommended to normalize the rate of change. 
In b): I guess that I need to calculate the jacobian matrix and the hessian matrix of $f(x,y)$ and use lagrange multiplier, right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x$ and $y$ depends on $t$, so you get $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$, plug in to the height function, you get

$$f(x,y)=f(x(t),y(t))=g(t)$$

So you get a single variable function for the height $g(t)$. Now you can apply the calculus tool to find its maxima.